# src value not taken from root in firefox, works fine in chrome

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, src

I have an `img` tag which has a src. This is working fine in chrome but not in firefox.

When I investigated, I learnt that firefox is not taking path from the root but appending the src path to the url. I want the path of the image to be taken from root. I tried searching on the net and did found a few fixes. I have tried them but with no luck. I can provide them if requested.

The img code is

```
<img src="\img\common\Web-award-logo-money-1.png" alt="Money partner of the year"
                                    style="border: 0;"></div>
```

When I write

> ..\img\common\Web-award-logo-money-1.png

it starts to display the image. The original code is working fine in chrome.
Please let me know if you need any further information at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would try and use / instead of \ af

Comment: I would try using / instead of \ afaik your syntax is windows specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you have the wrong '\' its meant to be '/' so the correct code would be:

`<img src="/img/common/Web-award-logo-money-1.png" alt="Money partner of the year" style="border: 0;">`

Comment: Nice one! Such a simple mistake and such havoc! :)